# Ordenar un "select" por nombre y no por ID

Tags: php, select, ordenamiento

como están? Necesito ayuda para resolver este problema.

Tengo un "select" que por defecto se ordena por numero de ID cuando los creo, pero yo necesito que esto se ordene alfabeticamente por el apellido de las personas.

```
<select name = "booking [agent_id]" class = "os-form-control agent-selector">
                   <? php foreach ($ agents as $ agent) {?>
                     <option value = "<? php echo $ agent-> id;?>" <? php if ($ agent-> id == $ booking-> agent_id) echo 'selected'; ? >> <? php echo join ('', array ($ agent-> first_name, $ agent-> last_name)); ?> </option>
                   <? php}?>
                 </select>
```

.

```
<select name="booking[agent_id]" class="os-form-control agent-selector">
                                      <option value="5">Rubén  Rivarola</option>
                                      <option value="4">Agustin Markus</option>
                                      <option value="6">Carlos Fenianos</option>
                                      <option value="7">David Carlos</option>
                                      <option value="8">Ana María Budetta</option>
                                      <option value="9">Carlos Codesal Blanco</option>
                                      <option value="10">Braga Guillermo</option>
                                      <option value="11">Roxana Aloisio</option>
                                      <option value="12">Richard Ariñez</option>
                                      <option value="13">Cesar Salomone</option>
                                      <option value="14">Mónica Bellido</option>
                                      <option value="15">Laura Camargo</option>
                                      <option value="16">Canonici  Lorena</option>
                                      <option value="17">Mirta Garay</option>
                                      <option value="18">Carlos  Cohen</option>
                                      <option value="19">Savino Graciela</option>
                                      <option value="20">Sergio Panese</option>
                                  </select>
```

Desde ya, agradezco mucho su ayuda!

Comment: Cómo obtienes los valores de `$agents`?

Comment: En el caso de que estes utilizando BD, te recomiendo utilizar el metodo `orderBy` para que puedas definir el orden

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza [`asort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.asort.php) para ordenar por valor.

> Esta función ordena un array manteniendo la correlación de los índices del array con los elementos con los que están asociados. Esta función se utiliza principalmente para ordenar arrays asociativos en los que el orden es importante.

En caso de que tu array no estuviera ordenado por id y lo quisieras así, utilizarías [`ksort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ksort.php). Pero una mejor recomendación sería ordenarlos desde su origen.

```php
asort($agents);
```